# xen create new virtual machine using command line

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I want to create (CentOS) virtual machine using xen by `virt-install` command

I am using kickstart and put it in `http://192.168.1.8/centos/kickstart.cfg` 
and put Centos 6.5 in  `http://192.168.1.8/centos/os/`
[image]

use

`[root@CentOS ~]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/lib/xen/images/vserver.img bs=1M count=4000`

`[root@CentOS ~]# virt-install -p -n vserver -r 512 -f /var/lib/xen/images/vserver.img  -l http://192.168.1.8/centos/os -x ks=http://192.168.1.8/centos/kickstart.cfg -w bridge:xenbr0 --vcpus=1`

the result

`Starting install...
ERROR    Could not find an installable distribution at 'http://192.168.1.8/centos/os'
The location must be the root directory of an install tree.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect xen:/// start vserver
otherwise, please restart your installation.`

Comment: This question clearly belongs to SuperUser and not SO. But then again, I'm already here, so might as well help: Is there a reason why you don't use network installation method of virsh?

Comment: I am deleting it from SuperUser because no one answer me, so I ask it here

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain more?

Comment: If nobody answers to your question in SuperUser within a day or so, you might take that as a hint for the question itself being the problem. For example, maybe you could rewrite your question to include more information/leave out unnecessary repetition and so on. Most folks really like to help but helping them in helping you by writing good questions is a part of the deal.

Comment: See `man virt-install` and especially the part about `--location`. That way you can use network URIs as installation media, no need to copy things in your local hard disk and serve them with HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's need the .treeinfo file,

```
vi /var/www/html/centos/os/.treeinfo
```

and add this lines:

```
[general]
family = CentOS
timestamp = 1341518023.56
variant = 
totaldiscs = 1
version = 6.5
discnum = 1
packagedir = 
arch = i386

[images-i386]

initrd = images/pxeboot/initrd.img

[images-xen]

initrd = isolinux/initrd.img
kernel = isolinux/vmlinuz

[stage2]
mainimage = images/install.img
```

don't copy it directly from the browser, write it by keyboard or copy it to a text file first, in order to remove any special characters.

finally give Apache ownership to the files:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/*
```

In the virt-install command add the CentOS (URL) as string 
and use `--bridge=xenbr0` instead of `bridge:xenbr0`

```
[root@CentOS ~]# virt-install -p -n vserver -r 512 -f /var/lib/xen/images/vserver.img  -l "http://192.168.1.8/centos/os" -x -w --bridge=xenbr0 --vcpus=1
```

P.S: change the arch field if you are using 64bit version to x86_64